# Get instruction type in LLVM C API

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In the LLVM C Api, instructions are passed around by LLVMValueRef. How do I determine what instruction type (add, store, fence, whatever) an LLVMValueRef is, if it's an instruction at all?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for this: in 2016 a `LLVMGetValueKind` function was added: https://reviews.llvm.org/D18729.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's LLVMTypeOf and then LLVMTypeKind functions to get a type enumeration from a value.

Comment: I've found it difficult to search the LLVM C documentation. Do you have the links?

Comment: This gives you the type of the value (e.g. i8, i32* etc.), not the kind of instruction (e.g. load, store, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are `LLVMIsA*` functions for each value subclass. They're maybe a bit hard to find because they're generated by macros. [The declarations, in `Core.h`, look like this](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8h_source.html#l01305):

```
#define LLVM_DECLARE_VALUE_CAST(name) \
  LLVMValueRef LLVMIsA##name(LLVMValueRef Val);
LLVM_FOR_EACH_VALUE_SUBCLASS(LLVM_DECLARE_VALUE_CAST)
```

And [the definitions, in `Core.cpp`, look like this](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8cpp_source.html#l00594):

```
#define LLVM_DEFINE_VALUE_CAST(name)                                       \
  LLVMValueRef LLVMIsA##name(LLVMValueRef Val) {                           \
    return wrap(static_cast<Value*>(dyn_cast_or_null<name>(unwrap(Val)))); \
  }

LLVM_FOR_EACH_VALUE_SUBCLASS(LLVM_DEFINE_VALUE_CAST)
```

So for an `LLVMValueRef V` should be able to write e.g. `LLVMIsAStoreInst(V)`, which will return either the same value back or null. Intermediate subclasses also work, as in e.g. `LLVMIsAInstruction(V)`, `LLVMIsAConstant(V)`, etc.

Alternatively, for instructions in particular, you can use [`LLVMGetInstructionOpcode`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8h_source.html#l02404), and compare the enum against [the `LLVMOpcode` values](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8h_source.html#l00176). It will also conveniently return `0` if the argument is not an instruction.

Incidentally (in response to your comment), I think the header files are often the best place to look for LLVM documentation, as the doxygen docs are sometimes confusing. For example `Core.h` is pretty straightforward to read through, and [this comment](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8h_source.html#l01136) answers your question.